# Rendering Mathjax in a html custom element (shadow DOM)

Tags: mathjax, shadow-dom, custom-element

Custom elements are a pretty important part of the page i'm writing, and some of them are meant to include math. I cannot currently get a tex expression inside a custom element to render with MathJax. See the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script>
        MathJax = {
          tex: {
            inlineMath: [['_(','_)']],
            displayMath: [['_($', '_)']],
          },
          svg: {
            fontCache: 'global'
          }
        };
    </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>
    Hi! My name's buster. Here's some _(1+2+3_) cool as 
    _($\text{MATH}_)
    How's it going.
    </p>

    <bus-but> Hi there! I am _(3^4_) quite _(\frac{5}{7}_) good! </bus-but>

</body>

<script>

    class HoverVideo extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            //Create shadow
            var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

            //Make element
            var theElement = document.createElement('div');
            theElement.setAttribute("id", "coolElement")
            theElement.style = "background-color: red;"

            shadow.appendChild(theElement);

        }

        connectedCallback() {
            this.shadowRoot.getElementById("coolElement").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML="";
            
            console.log(MathJax);
        }
    }
    customElements.define("bus-but",HoverVideo);

</script>
```

Here we have a simple customElement that inserts it's contents in a div element with a red background. I've configured MathJax to use "*(" and "*)" for it's math delimeters, so
ideally  "3^4" and  " \frac{5}{7}" should render. Instead i get:

[image: Result]

I've tried using MathJax tex2svg functionality as well, but even though the docs mention the existance of functions like "MathJax.tex2chtml", when i call from the custom element, the console informs me that the function tex2chtml doesn't exist. This is strange since the customElement *is* aware of the MathJax variable (i can log it and see it's contents).

Comment: Have you tested it **without** shadowDOM? Most likely cause is MathJAX is loaded and can only process global content, it can't get _into_ shadowDOM just like it can't get _into_ IFrames

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Wasn't actually aware that you could use customElements *without* the shadow DOM. Do you just append your elements to the "this" variable instead, then?

Comment: Yes, shadowDOM is only required when you want its **encapsulation** features. I guess MathJax will only work in global accessible DOM elements. Replace ``shadow`` with ``this``; and without shadowDOM you do that in the ``connectedCallback``, not the ``constructor`` (which is an in Memory only state, the DOM isn't there yet)